# while i want to return the resulted string in (convert class) it throw an error based on not being initialized conversion string

Tags: java

```
public class Convert {

   String[] firstDigit = {"","zero","one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ,"six" ,"seven" ,"eight" ,"nine"};
   String[] tenToNineteen = {"ten", "eleven" ,"twelve" ,"thirteen" ,"fourteen" ,"fifteen" ,"sixteen" ,"seventeen" ,"eighteen" ,"nineteen"};
   String[] secondDigit = {"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};
   String[] thirdDigit = {"","hundred", "two hundred", "three hundred", "four hundred", "five hundred", "six hundred", "seven hundred", "eight hundred", "nine hundred"};
   //String[] thirdDigit = {"", "hundred"};
   String[] fourthDigit = {"","one thousand "};

   public String convertToLetter(int num){

     String conversion;  
     int numCopy = num;
     int counter = 1;

     int[] digits = {0,0,0,0,0};


      while (numCopy > 0){

        digits[counter] = numCopy % 10;
        numCopy /= 10;
        counter ++;

      }

      //cheking 
     System.out.println(+digits[0]);
     System.out.println(+digits[1]);
     System.out.println(+digits[2]);
     System.out.println(+digits[3]);
     System.out.println(+digits[4]);     
     System.out.println("*******************************");


       switch (counter) {

           case 1 :
               conversion = firstDigit[digits[1]+1];
           case 2 :
               if ( digits[2] == 1)
                   conversion = tenToNineteen[digits[digits[1]]+1];
               conversion = secondDigit[digits[2]]+" "+firstDigit[digits[1]+1];
           case 3 :
               if (digits[2] == 1)
                   conversion = thirdDigit[digits[3]]+" and "+tenToNineteen[digits[1]+1];
               conversion = thirdDigit[digits[3]]+" and "+secondDigit[digits[2]]+" "+firstDigit[digits[1]+1];
           case 4 :
               if (digits[2] == 1)
                   conversion = fourthDigit[digits[4]]+" and "+thirdDigit[digits[3]]+" and "+tenToNineteen[digits[num%10]+1];
               conversion = fourthDigit[digits[4]]+thirdDigit[digits[3]]+" and "+secondDigit[digits[2]]+" "+firstDigit[digits[1]+1];
       }

        return conversion;


   }
}
```

Comment: Change: `String conversion;`  To: `String conversion = "";`

Comment: What happens when I supply a 5 or 6 digit number? Oh what the heck...what if I want to convert `Long.MAX_VALUE` to Numerical words (which works out to something like: **Nine Quintillion Two Hundred Twenty Three Quadrillion Three Hundred Seventy Two Trillion Thirty Six Billion Eight Hundred Fifty Four Million Seven Hundred Seventy Five Thousand Eight Hundred Seven**) or something like that.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is `String conversion;`. This line declares the variable `conversion` but does not initialize it. In the `switch`, the String gets a value if `counter` is 1, 2, 3 or 4, but not otherwise. The error is thrown because the String is not always initialized. An easy way to fix it is:

```
String conversion = "";
```

In the `switch` instead of writing `conversion = ...;`, you should write `conwersion += ...;` to append the new String to this one. Now the program should work without any problems.

Or you can do what user9335240 did and use the StringBuilder class.

Answer (score -1):

You can apply the comment on this question.

Or, for something better in performance, use `StringBuilder`.
`String` is immutable in Java, this makes every append as creation of a new object every addition. But `StringBuilder` contains "mutable info" on the additions/removals on string, then you can build a string from it, just one time.

```
StringBuilder conversion = new StringBuilder();
```

When you want to append anything, use

```
conversion.append(whatToAdd);
```

Where `whatToAdd` may be almost anything, you can append char, int, double, float, String or Object.

When you want to build, use

```
conversion.toString();
```

In your case, you want to return it.

```
return conversion.toString();
```

Read about this at the Oracle Documentation

[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html)